# How to format user entered tags in php?

Tags: php, tags, keyword, str-replace

I've been searching for a while but I have yet to find my answers. I'm trying to format my tags so they either come out as one word or multiple words depending on how a user entered them.

For example, when a user enters: social, bookmarking, social media

I get these three seperate tags... "social" "bookmarking" "media"

I need it to show as these three tags.... "social" "bookmarking" "social media"

Notice social media is one word. the quotes are just to help explain, they don't actually show up. Also some users are using spaces instead of commas to seperate tags despite my instructions and it's making one long tag instead.

Here is the whole code I'm using now...

```
        $query="SELECT gtags FROM posts WHERE category='".mysql_real_escape_string($CATID)."' order by rand() limit 20";
    $results=$conn->execute($query);
    $gtags = $results->getrows();
    for($i=0; $i<count($gtags);$i++)
    {
        $tags .= $gtags[$i][0].",";
    }
    $tags = str_replace("  ", ",", $tags);
    $tags = str_replace(".", ",", $tags);
    $tags = str_replace("/", ",", $tags);
    $tags = str_replace("+", ",", $tags);
    $tags = str_replace("", " ", $tags);
    $tags = str_replace(" ", ",", $tags);
    $tags = explode(",", implode(",", array_unique(explode(",", $tags))));
    STemplate::assign('tags',$tags);
    $templateselect = "tags.tpl";
```

Comment: You should split your 2 questions since they are not related (not much at least)

Comment: users should be selecting tags from a list maybe, otherwise you will end up with loads of similar tags with typos and so on.  Allow them to add new tags, sure, then only one tag at a time. Use Ajax, I've seen a few slick implementations.

Answer (score 0):

You can use explode to transform a comma separated list to an array. You can explode on spaces too, but explode isn't smart enough to know that the space in `social media` is not a separator, while the space in social bookmarking is.

I think you'd best train your users to use comma's. You can also provide a multiline edit (textarea) to enter the keywords and have them enter one on each line, optionally allowing commas too. But if you're allowing spaces as separators, you won't be able to have spaces within a tag unless you query all tags first and check against that list. But what if your user actually meant to enter the keywords "social" and "media"?  ...

Answer (score 0):

If your users enter their tags separated by commas, you can create an array of tags by exploding the string: `$all_tags = explode(',', $tag_string);`

If your users do not enter the commas, you are stuck, because you are going to have no idea if the user intended a tag to be one word or more (in other words, you can't explode with the space character as a delimeter).

You could set up an AJAX call to your tags table which returns tags as the user types. When they click the correct tag in the list, add it to their list of tags. This will eliminate the problem, but you'll have to work out what to do when the user wants to add a tag or multiple tags that are not in the table already.

Comment: So basically unless the user does it right it's not going to work. I suppose PHP can't read minds...yet. Right now I am forcing each tag to be seperate ($tags = str_replace(" ", ",", $tags);) but I have to do this otherwise tags seperated by spaces become one gigantic tag. Is it possible to at least fix this somehow?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you're asking... is it possible to fix at least what?

Answer (score 0):

a better approach:

```
$search = array(
    "a",
    "b",
    "c"
);
$replace = array(
    "1",
    "2",
    "3"
);
$str = str_replace($search, $replace, $str);
```

i would only allow users to select the tags from a list for several reasons:

- most users dont know how to properly tag, they might even create tags like (caps included) "BEST SOCIAL MEDIA SITE 2011"
- you can have lots of grammar mistakes
- no real "pattern"
- and more that you can think of ;P

imo the better way to do this is to create your own tag database and then allow user to select multiple tags from a input:text + autocomplete (jquery), or something more simple like a select or checkbox

just wanted to add my opinion